Why does my Lottie animation starts after content is loaded in React application?
I'm using react-lottie to animate a set of Lottie animations on a React page. I have an array of animation data (items) that each corresponds to a different animation, and I'm trying to cycle through these animations based on both user interaction and automatically.
Here’s a simplified version of the code I'm using:
Code setup:

Items Array:

My items array includes the animationData which holds the json object for Lottie, title and description are strings to show on the page.
const items = [
    {
        animationData: layer1Animation,
        title: 'social gaming experiences',
        description: 'we develop entertaining engagement formats on the best social gaming platforms...',
    },
    // other items
];


Default Options for Lottie:

For the react-lottie, I should have options object which holds the parameters:
const defaultOptions = {
    loop: false,
    autoplay: true,
    animationData: items[activeIndex].animationData,
    rendererSettings: {
        preserveAspectRatio: 'xMidYMid slice',
    },
};



Event Listeners:

According to the answer below, I have added the eventListeners to the lottie to animate the index once the previous one is finished:
const eventListeners = [
    {
        eventName: 'complete',
        callback: handleAnimationComplete,
    },
];

const handleAnimationComplete = () => {
    setActiveIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % items.length);
};



Rendering:

As for the rendering, I am rendering the card_items which holds the animation and content:
<div className={styles.container}>
    <h3>but what are our actual solutions?</h3>
    <div className={styles.cart_items}>
         <div className={`${styles.cart_item} ${styles.active}`}>
             <div className={styles.image_container}>
                 <Lottie
                     key={activeIndex}
                     options={defaultOptions}
                     eventListeners={eventListeners}
                     height={400}
                 />
             </div>
             <div className={styles.content}>
                 <p>{items[activeIndex].title}</p>
                 <span>{items[activeIndex].description}</span>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div className={styles.animation_slider}>
        {items.map((_, index) => (
            <div
                key={index}
                onClick={() => setActiveIndex(index)}
                className={index === activeIndex ? styles.active : styles.inactive}
            ></div>
        ))}
    </div>
</div>

Problem
The issue appears once the index changes. So, when the index changes and a new animation is loaded, there is a noticeable delay (approximately 0.5 seconds or more) before the new animation starts. The content updates immediately, but the Lottie animation does not, leading to a jarring visual effect where the content changes while the previous animation is still playing. This delay causes a poor user experience as it disrupts the fluidity of the animation transitions.
** I have tried:**

I’ve set up event listeners to trigger handleAnimationComplete which updates the index. However, the delay persists despite these listeners firing correctly.
I’m using key={activeIndex} on the Lottie component to ensure the component re-renders when the index changes, but this does not resolve the timing issue.

Current result

How it should be:

As showed in above result, I'm not quite sure why there is such delay in the animation. Ideally, the animation should start immediately as soon as the index changes and the content updates seamlessly, but currently there is around 0.5s delay each animation starts after the content.
Thus, to conclude, why does my lottie animation starts to autoplay with some delay?
You can also check the code at this codesandbox.

Please stop deleting the quesiton content. You're the OP. You can delete the whole question. A behavior like this usually causes a ban on this platform.

I cannot delete the question itself because someone submitted the chatGPT answer and others upvoted that even that does not solve the issue i'm having.

I can delete my downvoted questions with upvoted answer, but I get: _" Delete this answered question?
We do not recommend deleting questions with answers because doing so deprives future readers of this knowledge. See "I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?" for alternatives to deletion.
Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking. Are you sure you wish to delete?"_ Maybe you shouldn't do it too often.

"you can use a flag to request that moderators delete it" "Vandalizing or excessive deletion of useful posts may trigger an alert within the system, and prompt action from the moderation team."

@jabaa what annoying this is that I have spent literally quite some time on the project and also on the question, but getting these many downvotes just shows how the community is. There are worse questions with no content, but still did not get flagged or such, so I just don't understand this logic.

I've already explained it multiple times. Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform for specific questions. You haven't asked a specific question. You've described, what you want. Stack Overflow is not a code writing or code debugging service. Your question doesn't even contain a question mark (?) outside the code snippets. A question mark is not enough for a specific question. The problem is not the community, but your misunderstanding of how this platform works.

Question does not need to have question mark, but if the question explains the problem clearly it is enough for it to be a question here. If you would actually like to help maybe editing the question with better content would actually help which other people do.

Interestingly no one actually wanted to help, but just blaim the OP that question mark is missing.

I'm the one user who voted to close and if I could, I would vote to delete, because I think that "Fix my code" questions are not helpful for future users. That's why I also wouldn't invest time in improving this question. I don't think, this is a good question for Stack Overflow. Why does it even bother you? I have a question with -12 and one question with -10. I've upvoted all answers because I think, the answers are helpful. I could delete my questions instead, but I didn't. Why are upvotes or reputation so important to you? And even with -50, I wouldn't delete the questions.

@jabaa when someone downvotes my question I would like to actually see the reason why it is downvoted and currently there are 6 downvotes which means 6 different people and none of them actually tried to explain why they downvoted in comments or at least tried to edit the question, so I could learn how to ask it properly. I have been using the platform for some time and answered quite some questions and did not downvoted a question without giving a reason.

As I've already explained, it's not necessary to comment or edit a question. If you want to know, how to ask, you can read [tour], [ask], How to debug small programs, Why is "Can someone help me?" not a useful question?, How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?

You should post a [mcve] as code in your question, not a link to an external resource with your code. When should I make edits to code? How could anybody improve your question if you haven't even asked a question.

If there is no easy way to have reproducible code on Stackoverflow, it is common to link it to codesandbox, jsfiddle and other kind of platforms, no?

No, questions are for the future, not for you. If you post a link that contains necessary details, and the link breaks or the content changes, the question and the answer become worthless. It maybe common for new users, but it's wrong. If there is no easy way, it usually means that you haven't invested enough effort to debug the code and isolate the problem.

@jabaa that might be the case, yes, but my question is related to gsap with react and there was no easy way of having reproducible code here, if it was simple html/css then I would just post it with no problems.

It seems like you don't want to understand the downvotes. It also seems like you've ignored everything I've told you and all the links. If there is no easy way, it means that you have to invest more effort, not that we have to make an exception for you.

Okay, thanks. I will need to find a way to delete the question as the answer is just chatgpt answer which does not even solve the issue.

I have read the links you have provided, and updated my question regarding to that. I hope this time I have achieved having good question.

I would try to add code snippet, but I guess it is not possible.

I've removed my downvote and retracted my close vote. Why should it be impossible to add a code snippet? It doesn't have to be a runnable snippet.

@jabaa thank you, i took some time to read the articles you mentioned, I guess the important thing is the title indeed. So, how other users who downvoted will be notified and remove their downvotes?

I always follow questions when I vote or comment to be notified when something happens.

@jabaa I see. I hope others did the same.

it could be possible that the animation is less than or more that the timeout specified, try using the onComplete event listener instead of timeout
Add this to your options
eventListeners=[
      {
        eventName: 'complete',
        callback: () => onComplete,
      },
   ]

add a new function
const onComplete () => {
    setActiveIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % items.length);
}

LINK: https://github.com/chenqingspring/react-lottie?tab=readme-ov-file#props

@NijatMursali Thats outside the scope of this site

@NijatMursali This isn't a code writing service

@NijatMursali I have updated the code in the sandbox, please try in your own project

@mousetail as you did not reply, I'm guessing you do not have answer to the question.

@srivenkatasuryavamsivarma I have tried this solution, but for some reason it does not go to next index automatically.

since you are loading all the components at once it is happening like instead try loading one at a  time
check this implementation
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/t7mfd8

@srivenkatasuryavamsivarma yes, I know, but the problem is with the animation start time. It starts around 0.5ms after index changes, thus animation is not really smooth. In reference screenshot I attached in the question they change simultaneously, and that is the problem at the moment.

@srivenkatasuryavamsivarma could you please remove your answer to the question? I will be removing the question as it got many downvotes which I don't understand why.

@mrconcerned One reason is: Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform for specific questions. I can't find a specific question. How to debug small programs StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site for specific questions about actual code; “I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix” is not a question, it’s a story, and not even an interesting story. Why is "Can someone help me?" not a useful question?

@jabaa interesting as it is first time for me getting these much downvotes and actually community got worse as I can tell. You mentioned there is no specific question, but I already mentioned that the problem is with animation where it is a bit off from the content which means animation of Lottie starts after some delay of index change.

@mrconcerned Maybe it's a language problem, but "the problem is with animation where it is a bit off from the content which means animation of Lottie starts after some delay of index change" is not a question. It's a problem description. The implicit question "How can I fix it" is similar to Why is "Can someone help me?" not a useful question?

@mrconcerned No, actually users with lower reputation can't even comment if the comment contains an explanation for their downvote. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325416/why-isnt-it-required-to-provide-comments-feedback-for-downvotes-and-why-are-pr

@jabaa thank you, I have updated the question. Could you please let me know if it explains the issue completely or I need to add further information?

@mrconcerned A question ends with a question mark "?". See the examples in the [tour]. A specific question asks about a specific problem. Dumping your whole code and asking why it doesn't work isn't considered a specific question. Where are your debugging details? Have you stepped line by line with your debugger through the code?

@jabaa I have now added question mark.

@mrconcerned "So, could anyone tell me how to fix this issue?" is not a specific question and should be downvoted. How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users? Stack Overflow is the last place to search for an answer, not the first place. "In fact, asking a question on Stack Overflow is the absolute last thing you ever want to do. ... If the information that you need already exists, then you should be able to find it before asking."

@jabaa Thank you for your recommendations. I have updated my question and hopefully it explains the problem.

@mrconcerned Why do you think that "What I Need Help With" is different to Why is "Can someone help me?" not a useful question? IMO, "What I Need Help With" and "Can someone help me" are the same questions.

@jabaa I guess it is just going to be debate here instead of actually asking and getting answers. Stackoverflow gives an option to edit the questions, so if someone wanted to be helpful here would just edit the question with better explanation and I am sure my explanation in the question is more than enough for someone to understand the problem statement, but of course for a community like this it is better to downvote the questions and just give some unnecessary suggestions in the comments.

@srivenkatasuryavamsivarma could you please remove your answer to the question as it does not solve the problem i had (also included in the question), I will be removing the question.

@mrconcerned Please don't ask other users to delete their posts. sri venkata surya vamsi varma invested time and effort to answer your question and 4 users think that this answer is helpful.

@jabaa it does not solve the problem which is stated in question itself.

@mrconcerned Stack Overflow is a wiki-like question and answer platform with the goal to collect questions and answers to help future users with similar problems. 4 users think, that this answer could help future users. The goal is not to help one user with their individual problem, especially since there is no specific question.

@jabaa yeah, OK.
